# Increase the size of my form , when user maximizes the window, in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

In eclipse i have a layout with table , buttons text fields. I have created them in the:

```
public class NewForm extends FormPage{
    @Override
    protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) {
        FormToolkit ftk= managedForm.getToolkit();

    ScrolledForm scrldfrm = managedForm.getForm();
    scrldfrm.getBody().setLayout(null);
    scrldfrm.setText("Hello there!");
    Section section = managedForm.getToolkit().createSection(
            managedForm.getForm().getBody(),
            Section.TWISTIE | Section.TITLE_BAR);
    section.setBounds(522, 10, 374, 21);
    managedForm.getToolkit().paintBordersFor(section);
    section.setText("Selected API");
    section.setExpanded(true);
    textName = new Text(managedForm.getForm().getBody(), SWT.BORDER);
    textName.setBounds(610, 67, 275, 21);
    managedForm.getToolkit().adapt(textName, true, true);
    textName.setEnabled(false);
    //similarly table is added.
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until the user maximizes the window. After maximizing the window, the form contents remain at same position, well I have used absolute values in the form. How to make it increase size when window re-sizes? If i should not give absolute values in form, the how to avoid absolute values and give values relative to window size?

Comment: Show us a bit more of you form creating code.

Comment: @greg-449 done! have alook at it. I just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Layout` rather than `setBounds` calls. `GridLayout` is one possibility or `FormLayout`.

Something like:

```
ScrolledForm scrldfrm = managedForm.getForm();

scrldfrm.getBody().setLayout(new GridLayout());

scrldfrm.setText("Hello there!");

Section section = managedForm.getToolkit().createSection(
        managedForm.getForm().getBody(),
        Section.TWISTIE | Section.TITLE_BAR);

section.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

managedForm.getToolkit().paintBordersFor(section);
section.setText("Selected API");
section.setExpanded(true);

textName = new Text(managedForm.getForm().getBody(), SWT.BORDER);

textName.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);

managedForm.getToolkit().adapt(textName, true, true);
textName.setEnabled(false);
```